# Amazon Rekognition - Detect Faces - not returning all attributes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

I am calling the Amazon Rekognition Detect faces API from Post man. I pass the image as base64 and pass the "Attributes" as ["ALL"].

```
{
"Image": {
"Attributes":  ["ALL"],
"Bytes": <base64 image>
}
}
```

The response I get is as below. You can see that it has only a few attributes and does not include age range, beard, glasses etc. Same set of attributes are returned irrespective of whether I pass the value as "ALL", or "DEFAULT" or "ALL","DEFAULT" in the Attributes parameter.
Am I missing something here? Any pointers would be much appreciated.

```
{
"FaceDetails": [
    {
        "BoundingBox": {
            "Height": 0.49429410696029663,
            "Left": 0.35876789689064026,
            "Top": 0.15820752084255219,
            "Width": 0.3210359811782837
        },
        "Confidence": 100.0,
        "Landmarks": [
            {
                "Type": "eyeLeft",
                "X": 0.4103875756263733,
                "Y": 0.35949569940567017
            },
            {
                "Type": "eyeRight",
                "X": 0.5616039037704468,
                "Y": 0.3441786468029022
            },
            {
                "Type": "mouthLeft",
                "X": 0.4385274350643158,
                "Y": 0.5330458879470825
            },
            {
                "Type": "mouthRight",
                "X": 0.5625125169754028,
                "Y": 0.5202205181121826
            },
            {
                "Type": "nose",
                "X": 0.48630291223526,
                "Y": 0.436920166015625
            }
        ],
        "Pose": {
            "Pitch": 8.636483192443848,
            "Roll": -5.8078813552856445,
            "Yaw": -3.338975429534912
        },
        "Quality": {
            "Brightness": 82.37736511230469,
            "Sharpness": 83.14741516113281
        }
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Please edit the question to show us the code where you actually call Rekognition? That way, we can try to reproduce the situation. Thank you.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - I am calling this from Postman.